# Speed up file searching with this trick in FindFirstFile-FindNextFile?

Tags: winapi

I would like to know about the FindFirstFile and the following first FindNextFile.
Is it true, that FindFirstFile ALWAYS find the '.' (current folder) and the following FindNextFile ALWAYS the '..' (parent folder)? The mask of course is '*'. I want a little speed up file listing, could I write something, like:

```
h := FindFirstFile('path\*' ...)     // it finds '.', not process
if h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then ... // some error handling, of course
FindNextFile(...)                    // skipping '..', I suppose, if '.' has found,
                                     // '..' will be too, no handle validity check
while FindNextFile(...) do
  // file/folder processing begins here
```

So I don't need checking '.' and '..' filenames in every cycle. Sorry for the syntax, I think, I was understandable, and for my english, if I made mistakes.

Comment: That is pointless and won't speed it up in any measurable way and merely obfuscates. I also can find nothing that could guarantee that ordering. In short there is nothing at all that can be said in favour of doing this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan And if "path" is "C:" you just threw away two perfectly good directory entries.

Comment: The only real way to speed up enumerating files in a directory is by directly accessing the [MFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Internals). However, things get complex down there, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: `FindFirstFileEx` can be quicker than `FindFirstFile` in some cases.

Comment: This may also fail for files on the network, depending on the software the server is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee at all that the first two entries will be `'. '` and `'..'`. So your proposed code cannot be used.

You could, I suppose, keep a track in a boolean of whether or not you have seen these two entries and if so skip the checks.

However, checking for these values is not your bottleneck. Enumerating directories involves trips to the disk and system calls. That is the bottleneck. Any attempt to optimise checking for these items will obfuscate your code and yield no discernible performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. One of my hobbies is to find best solutions, algorithms in short essential codes, (if needs, down to assembly level). In my practice it seemed true, I experienced that. But didn't find any documentation about it, I thought, it depends on Find*File inner behaviour and the data struct of harddrive.
This is why I asked. Thanks again.

Jonathan: I really used FindFirstFileEx with FIND_FIRST_EX_LARGE_FETCH, not like in sample code :) I thought using of Ex or not is irrelevant in the question.

IInspectable: You're right, I don't want to sink into MFT :)

I'll not use this form of code. I will use - as David suggests - a variable, but an integer type to counting occurannces down from 2, and if counter reaches 0 name checks don't need anymore.

Comment: It won't be any faster and your code will be obfuscated

Comment: I understood you, the bottleneck, I can't speed up API calls and disk accesses, but I followed in disasembler what does a simple string comparing. This bothers (obfuscates :) me. Please, don't laugh or take me seriously, it's a hobby. I'll write a specialized assembly code for comparing unicode '.' and '..'. May I'm too maximalist :)

Comment: Do it for fun, but don't kid yourself that your program will run faster.